# Generating random numbers for a probability density function in Python

Tags: python, scipy, probability-density

I'm currently working on a project relating to brownian motion, and trying to simulate some of it using Python (a language I'm admittedly very new at). Currently, my goal is to generate random numbers following a given probability density function. I've been trying to use the scipy library for it.

My current code looks like this:

```
>>> import scipy.stats as st
>>> class my_pdf(st.rv_continuous):
        def _pdf(self,x,y):
            return (1/math.sqrt(4*t*D*math.pi))*(math.exp(-((x^2)/(4*D*t))))*(1/math.sqrt(4*t*D*math.pi))*(math.exp(-((y^2)/(4*D*t))))
>>> def get_brown(a,b):
        D,t = a,b
        return my_pdf()
>>> get_brown(1,1)
<__main__.my_pdf object at 0x000000A66400A320>
```

All attempts at launching the *get_brown* function end up giving me these hexadecimals (always starting at 0x000000A66400A with only the last three digits changing, no matter what parameters I give for D and t). I'm not sure how to interpret that. All I want is to get random numbers following the given PDF; what do these hexadecimals mean?

Comment: You're printing an object reference. Maybe you wanted to call its `_pdf` method? Like `return my_pdf()._pdf(a,b)` or something?

Comment: [Is `y ^ 2` really supposed to use a bitwise operator?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_basic_operators.htm) Or did you mean `y ** 2`?

Comment: You're right, it should have been **, and I've moved to using my_pdf.pdf(a,b).

However, I think I'm still doing this wrong. It gives me a number now - always the same for given parameters - when what I'm trying to do is generate random (x,y) coordinates using the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

The result you see is the memory address of the object you have created. Now you might ask: which object? Your method `get_brown(int, int)` calls `return my_pdf()` which creates an object of the class `my_pdf` and returns it. If you want to access the `_pdf` function of your class now and calculate the value of the `pdf` you can use this code:

```
get_brown(1,1)._pdf(x, y)
```

On the object you have just created you can also use all methods of the `scipy.stats.rv_continous` class, which you can find [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html).

For your situation you could also discard your current code and just use the normal distribution included in `scipy` as Brownian motion is mainly a Normal random process.

Comment: Hm. I tried calling get_brown(1,1)._pdf(x, y), but all I got was "NameError: name 'y' is not defined"...

Answer (score 0):

As noted, this is a memory location. Your function `get_brown` gets an instance of the `my_pdf` class, but doesn't evaluate the method inside that class.

What you probably want to do is call the `_pdf` method on that instance, rather than return the class itself.

```
def get_brown(a,b):
    D,t = a,b  #  what is D,t for?
    return my_pdf()_pdf(a,b)
```

I expect that the code you've posted is a simplification of what you're really doing, but functions don't need to be inside classes - so the `_pdf` function could live on it's own. Alternatively, you don't need to use the `get_brown` function - just instantiate the `my_pdf` class and call the calculation method.